# Reapplying TRV - Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, visa-refusals

I applied TRV for Canada but I was refused. I am reapplying now but I get confused with the two questions. I've never applied in Canada other than TRV. Which one should I tick yes the letter b) or letter c)? They look like the same.

> b) Have you ever been refused a visa or permit, denied entry or ordered to leave Canada or any other country or territory?

> c) Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada?

Comment: It seems like your answer to both questions is "yes," so check both?

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestion, but I need concrete answer. ☺

Comment: The answer to both is **yes**. b) is asking about previous travel history in Canada *and* anywhere else; c) is asking about  previous applications to Canada. So ‘yes’ because b) you have previously been refused a TRV and c) you have previously applied to Canada.

Comment: @Traveller But isn't an "application to enter" what happens when one is physically at the border seeking entry? The Canada.gov TRV pages state that a TRV is not permission to enter Canada. I think it's like the US ESTA: permission to fly and approach, but the would-be entrant is still subject to refusal by the immigration officer. On these facts, I think the answer to question c) is "no."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica No, a TRV is a (Temporary Residence) Visa. The Canadian equivalent of an ESTA is an ETA.

Comment: @DJClayworth Fair enough, you're correct. However, a Canada TRV _behaves_ like an ESTA — or a visa of any kind — because having the TRV (or the visa) does not assure entry into the issuing country. We're in semantics-land here, discussing what Canada means by "applied to enter." I think that means being physically at the border, seeking to enter. Perhaps Canada means what you assert, but I think the different words ("refused a visa or permit" compared to "applied to enter") support a different conclusion.

Comment: Canadian immigration law and terminology is nowhere near as obscure as US. When they use a word it tends to have the obvious meaning.

Answer (score 6):

The two questions cover different situations. (b) covers any kind of refusal, denial of entry or deportation for any country. (c) covers all applications but only to Canada.

So if you had previously applied to Canada successfully and followed your visa conditions you would answer NO to (b) and YES to (c). If you had been refused entry to a country other than Canada you would answer YES to (b) but NO to (c).

**You would answer YES to both (b) and (c).**

Comment: Hi DJClayworth thank you for your answers. Let me just repeat myself I applied tourist visa for Canada and I was refused but I’ve never applied a visa to any other countries (except Canada). So, b) would be NO for me and c) would be YES for me. Am I right?

Comment: As I say in the answer: "You would answer YES to both." meaning (b) and (c). Because you have applied to Canada before (c) and you have been refused by Canada (b)

Comment: @MitchelAraw Which part of (b) referring to ‘Canada or any other country or territory’ is unclear? If you answer ‘No’ your new application will be denied and you’ll probably get a ban for deception.

Comment: Hi @DJClayworth,  thank you so much. You’ve been a great help. Really appreciate it.